# View eevee with black background

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm using Blender 2.83 on mac. I don't use any environment map. When switch to cycle, the my viewport has black background but in eevee, the background is grey. How can i make it black in eevee ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the World properties panel, you may either pick black color, or change the strength to 0.

This will cause the world not to emit any light, and render pitch black.